# Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy and iOS: How do I detect if device is bondable or not?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

Is it possible, using corebluetooth framework, to detect if peripheral is bondable?

Should I implement the failed to connect to delegate?

Comment: I want to answer this question very much but I don't know the answer for certain.  What I do know is that [it is possible to detect when "Pair" or "Cancel" is clicked on the request alert on the iOS device side](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12953887/981049).

Comment: yes, this is not enough unfortunately =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing at this time. With later versions of BLE, bonding information (GAP modes) is in the GAP profile, but not one bit of that information is available to you via CoreBluetooth. With the exception of some advertising data and limited scan response data, It only provides GATT information and below.

You could read any desired characteristic properties to see if it requires encryption (`CBCharacteristicPropertyNotifyEncryptionRequired`), which means you need to have a trusted connection (paired) to access it. That's as close as you're going to get for now.

You shouldn't be prompted to pair when you first connect, so `didFailToConnectPeripheral` won't help here. You'll only be prompted to pair after you attempt to read one of the encrypted characteristics. So, you should still know before the user is prompted if you check the properties of the characteristic first.

This from Apple's [Bluetooth Accessory Design Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf):

> The accessory should not request pairing until an ATT request is
>   rejected using the Insufficient Authentication error code. See the
>   Bluetooth 4.0 specification, Volume 3, Part F, Section 4 for details.
>
> If, for security reasons,the accessory requires a bonded relationship
>   with the Central,the Peripheral should reject the ATT request using
>   the Insufficient Authentication error code, as appropriate. As a
>   result, the Apple product may proceed with the necessary security
>   procedures.