# Is it possible to know if a user rejected bluetooth pairing on iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, firmware

So I am developing an application which interacts with a bluetooth peripheral, and I am running into the issue that there is currently no way to tell if the user rejected the peripheral's pairing request or not.

The current flow which is implemented is:

1. Scan for peripherals
2. Connect to peripheral
3. Discover services
4. Discover characteristics
   (Pairing request is sent here by the peripheral, and the OS presents the pairing permission popup)
5. Read from characteristics

I would like to present an error state if the user rejects the pairing request, but I do not seem to be able to tell whether this has happened:

- There is no error callback executed on the CBCentralManagerDelegate or CBPeripheralDeleagate
- All the characteristics are discovered, whether or not paring has been accepted
- Reading from/ writing to characteristics fails silently: i.e. the peripheral just doesn't return a value when a characteristic is read from, but there's no affirmative error to let me know that it's because of a permission failure.

According to [this article](https://medium.com/@kbabcockuf/bridging-the-gap-bluetooth-le-security-653078852c24) it indicates that there's no direct way to know that the pairing request was cancelled.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351579/bluetooth-4-0-low-energy-and-ios-how-do-i-detect-if-device-is-bondable-or-not) it looks as if there is not currently a direct way to detect whether a peripheral is bonded in iOS.

Is there any known workaround for this issue?

Comment: the BLE Central will be notified about if the client rejects the connection, via the [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518988-centralmanager)

Comment: The peripheral does not reject the connection.  Would this be the intended behavior of the peripheral firmware?  It seems like the documentation indicates that the peripheral would typically allow the central to connect and access public characteristics even if its not paired.