# Core-bluetooth pairing status of peripheral

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I'm currently developing a BLE app.
The app is simple.

I connect to a device with a specific service UUID.

I then try to read a characteristic which returns the "Invalid authentication" to force iOS to start the pairing.

When the pairing is done, I save the peripheral UUID to be able to call retrievePeripherals on the centralManager after killing and restarting the app.

1. Since iOS7 is there a way to tell if the user accepted the pairing or just tapped cancel ?
   This post tells it's not possible, but from iOS6.
   [iOS 6 CoreBluetooth Pairing / Forgetting (2 questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657940/ios-6-corebluetooth-pairing-forgetting-2-questions)
2. From this answer [IOS Bluetooth LE : unable to connect using stored pairing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589836/ios-bluetooth-le-unable-to-connect-using-stored-pairing-data/19605920#19605920)

   It tells you have to re-read the protected value on reconnection to force iOS to do the encryption. But I get the pairing alert on an already paired peripheral, it just does not make sense to me. Is this true ? Or is the encryption automatically done after connecting a paired peripheral ?
3. Since I store the peripheral UUID to be able to reconnect on app restart. I there a way for me to know if a peripheral is still paired or the user forgot the device from iOS bluetooth settings ?